# Linq get elements for the first N groups

Tags: vb.net, linq

I would like to get the first N groups elements with Linq of a ObservableCollection, an example trying to get the first 2 groups:

Data example:

```
GROUP1 item1
GROUP1 item2
GROUP1 item3
GROUP2 item1
GROUP2 item2
GROUP3 item1
GROUP3 item2
GROUP3 item3
GROUP4 item1
GROUP4 item2
GROUP4 item3
```

Result wanted:

```
GROUP1 item1
GROUP1 item2
GROUP1 item3
GROUP2 item1
GROUP2 item2
```

Hope someone can help me with this. Any ideas?

Can you provide a VB.Net sample?

Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly is stored in your `ObservableCollection`? Is it something like a `KeyValuePair`?  The code you have would be useful.

Comment: Hi Igor, the list has 3 properties: Group Number, Item Number and Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VB.NET (assuming that the collection is already sorted as you want):

```
Dim query = data.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Group).Take(2).SelectMany(Function(g) g)
```

Please see @svick's detailed explanation about inefficiencies of this approach...

Answer (score 3):

If your groups are always sorted like this, you can use `GroupBy()` to get all the groups, then `Take(2)` to get only the first two of them and then use `SelectMany()` to change the groups back into a single sequence:

```cs
data.GroupBy(x => x.Group)
    .Take(2)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Although this method can be inefficient, because it enumerates the whole collection. If you wanted to make it more efficient, you could write your own extension method that does this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> TakeGroups<T, TGroup>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TGroup> groupSelector, int groupLimit)
{
    int groupNumber = 0;
    TGroup lastGroup = default(TGroup);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (groupNumber == 0)
        {
            groupNumber = 1;
            lastGroup = groupSelector(item);
        }
        else
        {
            var currentGroup = groupSelector(item);
            if (!object.Equals(currentGroup, lastGroup))
            {
                groupNumber++;
                lastGroup = currentGroup;
            }
        }

        if (groupNumber > groupLimit)
            break;

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
data.TakeGroups(x => x.Group, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Svick for your answer. Same answer as Broken Glass, thank you !!

Comment: Hi Svick, Can you provide the VB.net version? Thanks so much !!

Answer (score 2):

```
myList.GroupBy(x=>x.GroupName).Where(x=>x.Key == "Group1" || x.Key == "Group2");
```

`Edit:` for the case you don't have groups name you should have list of possible group names or something like this, I named this group list as `groupList`:

```
myList.Where(x=>groupList.Contains(x=>x.GroupName);
```

Or if you always want first two groups do :

```
myList.GroupBy(x=>x.GroupName).OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Take(2).SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Comment: but, what if the group names are not known?

Comment: Hi Saeed, thanks for your feedback. I really don't know the name of the groups. Only know the count of groups I need to extract.

Comment: @my_tree_2012, I'd edit my answer, see it and if still something is ambiguous tell me.

Answer (score 2):

you can group by the group name, limit the number of groups to N (2 in the example) and then flatten the list again using `SelectMany()`:

```
var query = observableList.GroupBy(x=> x.GroupName)
                          .Take(2)
                          .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to post the same.  The other answers do not achieve the same goal.  The requirement is "get the first two groups and select everything in those groups".  The actual group names or how many items in each group are not known.

Comment: Thank you so much BrokenGlass, Igor too !!

Comment: I'm not agree with your answer but I'm not downvoting and left it to OP, what's the meaning of first two group? I think it should be at least sorted in alphabetically order or so.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, what's the meaning? Only the OP knows, but this is exactly what he asked for.

Comment: @Svick, I think I wrote in my comment, this is OPs responsibility to clarify meaning of first 2 groups. and if `p` is wrong p->q is always true, so I didn't downvote this answer, and everything BrokenGlass assumes is right. but that doesn't mean this is true answer for real application. (And to be clear, I'm saying this is OPs responsibility to clarify it not me and you).

Comment: Hi all, thanks so much for the answer. Can you post the code in vb.net ? Many thanks

Comment: I added a VB.NET version (by the way, there are free online C# to VB.NET converters)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Take(5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) or if you want to limit on groups, then you will just want to use the [Where method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

```
.Where(x=>(x.Group == "Group1" || x.Group == "Group2"));
//You COULD use Contains depending on your type
```

Comment: -1 Really I don't think always two groups consists of 5 elements. and your where clause always returns false. Also I can't understand upvoters to your answer.

Comment: Your update won't work either. How could `Group == "Group1"` *and* `Group == "Group2"` at the same time?

Comment: what if the group names are not known or how many items they have?

Comment: Really you answered first? your first answer (I think jus 5 second sooner than me) was list.Take(5)! and you got upvote for this! and your second answer, was wrong. now your third answer after 9 minute is true, but still has fake part (still you didn't delete your `take` part).